# How does SPSS assign factor scores for cases where underlying variables were pairwise deleted?

Tags: regression, spss, missing-data, factor-analysis

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to figure out from a report.  All analyses are being run in SPSS, which I don't have and don't use (my experience is with SAS and R).

They were running a regression to predict overall meal satisfaction from food type ordered, self-reported food flavor, and self-reported food texture.

But food flavor and texture are highly correlated, so they conducted a factor analysis, found food flavor and texture load on one factor, and used the factor scores in the regression.

However, about 40% of respondents don't have responses on self-reported food texture, so they used pairwise deletion while making the factors.

My question is when SPSS calculates the factor scores and outputs them as new variables in the data set, what does it do with people who had an input for a factor that was pairwise deleted?

How does it calculate (if it calculates it at all) factor scores for those people who had a response pairwise deleted during the creation of the factors and who therefore have missing data for one of the variables?

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand what pairwise deletion is. I suggest you [look it up](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21475199).

Comment: No, I understand exactly what pairwise deletion is.  My question is how does SPSS create factor scores for individuals who have been pairwise delted from the creation of that factor (or even if it creates scores for those individuals at all).

I'm trying to understand how an analysis worked, using a software program I don't use, from just the report of the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Factor scores are a linear combination of their scaled inputs. That is, given normalized variables X1, ..., Xn, we have the following (where LaTeX formatting isn't supported and the L's indicate the loadings)

f = \sum_{i=1}^n L_i X_i

In your case n = 2. Now suppose one of the X_i is missing. How do you take a sum involving a missing value? Clearly, you cannot... unless you impute it.

I don't know what the analyst who created your report did. I suggest you ask them.

Comment: You've sketched out my dilemma perfectly.  This isn't a statistical question at all - it's an SPSS defaults question. 

And you're correct that ideally I would just ask the analyst that did it, but unfortunately, they work for an outside vendor, I don't own the relationship or the contract, and they are notoriously slow to respond.  So while I'm trying to get them to answer, I figured I'd also try to get some SPSS wisdom from the crowd......

Comment: SPSS Statistics does just what you would expect.  If any inputs to a score calculation for a case are missing, then the calculated score is missing.